# bootstrap validator with remote file validation not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here I call the popup modal with remote file.

```
 <a data-toggle="modal" href="form.php" data-target="#feedback" > <b>Feedback</b></a>
```

Modal Code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="feedback" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" >


        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

I used the bootstrap validator `validator.min.js`

Inside the modal popup the validation not working.

I used the code from [Form reference](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/)

My form here is:

```
            <form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Cina Saffary" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputTwitter" class="control-label">Twitter</label>
        <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
        <input type="text" pattern="^([_A-z0-9]){3,}$" maxlength="20" class="form-control" id="inputTwitter" placeholder="1000hz" required>
        </div>
        <span class="help-block with-errors">Up to 20 letters, numbers and underscores</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" data-error="Bruh, that email address is invalid" required>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <input type="password" data-minlength="6" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
        <span class="help-block">Minimum of 6 characters</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPasswordConfirm" data-match="#inputPassword" data-match-error="Whoops, these don't match" placeholder="Confirm" required>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="radio">
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
        Boxers
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
        Briefs
        </label>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="terms" data-error="Before you wreck yourself" required>
        Check yourself
        </label>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

In modal popup the form validation not working. To fix this I used the below code. But no results.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#feedback').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#leave_feedback').validator();
});
```

});

How to implement the bootstrap validator validation inside the modal popup with remote file.  Please let me know.

Comment: I used the form code from http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

Comment: I guess you are missing the event like on click of that you need to validate

Comment: No. I also tried this method too $('#leave_feedback').validator().on('submit', function (e){  ... });